# Using setValue(value, forKey: key) on Int? types fires non key value coding-compliant method

Tags: swift, nsnumber, key-value-coding, nskeyvaluecoding

I'm successfully using the `setValue(value, forKey: key)` method in my NSKeyValueCoding compliant Swift NSObject subclass.

This works perfectly well on String optionals, e.g.

```
var name:String?
```

However, on Int optionals, it fails, triggering the undefined key method that I have overridden for debugging purposes:

```
override func setValue(value: AnyObject!, forUndefinedKey key: String!) {
    println("\(self) this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key \(key)")
}
```

So for example, a key of `myId` with a good integer value would trigger the undefined key method above.

```
var myId:Int?
```

If I change the above definition to be non-optional, then everything works fine:

```
var myId:Int = 0
```

With `myId` as an optional, I have tried absolutely everything I can think of in the way of casting, unwrapping, initialising, and so on. It just doesn't see the class as key value compliant for those numeric values.

I know that it is a good numeric value. Changing the var declaration to String? crashes. It also looks fine in lldb:

```
Printing description of key:
myId
key NSObject    0x00007fb8d530ca20  0x00007fb8d530ca20
k   NSString    "myId"  0x00007fa2aa942f20
value   __NSCFNumber *  Int64(4348129)  0xb000000004258e13
Printing description of value:
4348129
(lldb)
```

So, the question is, has anyone used - in Swift - the NSKeyValueCoding method `setValue(value, forKey: key)` **on an Int type** successfully?

Comment: Could this be because Int is of type Any and not AnyObject. I tried parsing an object to a dictionary and back and had similar problems. See https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao/blob/master/AppMessage/AppMessage/CloudKit/EVReflection.swift You can see I tried parsing the Any to an AnyObject. Nullable values are still a problem, but it works on an Int.

Answer (score 24):

KVO cannot function with pure Swift optionals because pure Swift optionals are not Objective-C objects.  Swift forbids the use of `dynamic` or `@objc` with generic classes and structures because there is no valid Objective-C equivalent, and so the runtime is not setup to support KVO on instances of those kinds of objects.  As for why it works with `String?`, that type is toll-free bridged to `NSString`, so it is semantically equivalent to `NSString *`, an Objective-C type that the runtime knows full-well how to deal with.  But compare that to `Int?` whose semantic equivalent would be `Optional<Int>`, not `UnsafePointer<Int>` or `NSNumber *` like you might expect.  For now, you'll need to convince the typechecker that it is safe to represent in Objective-C by using `NSNumber!`.

This is completely backwards and, in my opinion, an unfortunate limitation of the type system.  For any engineers that come across this post, see rdar://18624182.

Comment: I think there are a few technical inaccuracies in this post. 1) I've changed `Int?` to `NSNumber?`, and now it's fully KVO compliant.  2) KVO can function with optionals, as I can use `UIColor?`, `NSNumber?`, and other objc types. 3) Optionals are specially handled generics, and even added to Objc using `nonnullable`, `nullable`, .. etc.

Comment: 1 is implied by the final sentence of the first paragraph, 2 by the 3rd sentence, and 3 is wrong.  Optionals are bridged to a limited set of ObjC types by the runtime, but they are not completely representable with just the new nullable attributes.  Besides, this is about Swift structures and KVO, not Objective-C structures being bridged in.

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to ditch Swift types change:

```
var myId:Int?
```

to:

```
var myId:NSNumber?
```